# Git ERROR: Repository not found

Tags: git, forge

I've been reading through the other Git Repository not found errors but still struggling to fix the issue I'm having.

I'm working on a local repo pushing up to a Remote that is watched by Forge and gets deployed to production when updatingthe master branch. It isn’t deploying the changes that I'm pushing! I’ve made 4 contributions that haven’t been realised on the site. I’ve also tried deploying the code manually from within Forge via the deploy now button but that doesn’t work either. The error I’m getting is attached and below.

```
Fri Jun 29 08:30:42 UTC 2018
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I’m a contributor on the GitHub project. I’ve added my SSH key to my github account as well as Forge admin area so I can ssh into the Forge server.

When I run a `ssh -T git@github.com` on the Forge server, I get the name of another engineer who doesn't work on the project any more. So, I'm thinking the issue is with the Forge server as it doesn't have my key. So I tried:

```
ssh-copy-id forge@[ip address] I get the following:

INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that 
are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: WARNING: All keys were skipped because they 
already exist on the remote system.

(if you think this is a mistake, you may want to use -f option)
```

Should I force it?

Here is my .ssh/config

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

---

[edit] So running ssh -vvv git@github.com gives:

```
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/forge/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file 
/home/forge/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from github.com
```

Comment: If your Git setup for some other user, then yes absolutely you should fix that.

Comment: What just use -f to force it?

Answer (score 0):

> When I run a `ssh -T git@github.com` on the Forge server, I get the name of another engineer who doesn't work on the project any more. So, I'm thinking the issue is with the Forge server as it doesn't have my key.

That's correct, but somewhat incomplete.  More specifically, when you are on the Forge server and run `ssh -T git@github.com`, the Forge server offers *some* key to GitHub.  That key *does* exist, on both the Forge server *and* on GitHub.  GitHub uses that key, whatever it is, to find out who you are—and what's stored on GitHub says that *that* key belongs to the other engineer.

> ... `ssh-copy-id forge@[ip address]`

Presumably you are running this from some machine that has *your* GitHub keys.  If so, that's appropriate.

> [produces]
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: WARNING: All keys were skipped because they 
> already exist on the remote system.
>
> (if you think this is a mistake, you may want to use -f option)
> ```

You can indeed use `-f`.

I do all of this a rather different way, myself: I have an ssh key I use only for GitHub access, and configure the systems from which I intend to access GitHub thus:

```
$ cat $HOME/.ssh/config
[snip]
Host github.com
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id.github
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

(where `id.github` contains the private key and `id.github.pub` contains the public key).

I use a different <public, private> key-pair for each organization, which can make for complicated `.ssh/config` files, but means I am not giving everything out to everyone.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer @torek. Once I've created another ssh key and named it github how would I use ssh-copy-id to get that particular key on the forge server?

Comment: Forge suggests. Please make sure that the following SSH key (which I've left out for security reasons) is placed in both the /home/forge/.ssh/authorized_keys file and the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file on your server. Where do they mean when they say: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file on your server (is that my laptop?)

Comment: The `authorized_keys` file for any particular user account are keys that said account allows, i.e., if you have that key and deliver it to (in this case) Forge, they will believe that you are allowed to log in as that user. I'm not sure why they suggest both `/home/forge` *and* `/root` here, but both of those directories (and their contained `authorized_keys` files) would exist on the *Forge* server, not on your laptop. None of this affects logging in *from* the Forge server *to* GitHub.

Comment: So I checked the authorised_keys and the ssh key that Forge said to put in there is in there. Now I checked the connection status of the forge server in the dashboard and it is connecting successfully. When I click on deploy it still gives this error: ```Mon Jul 2 06:30:53 UTC 2018
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.```

I emailed Forge support and all they said was: Seems like the connected git user doesn't have access to this repository.

Comment: I don't know anything about Forge itself, hence no idea what "click on deploy" actually *does*. Maybe this explains why they say to put the key in two different places.

Comment: Deploy is running a script to pull from the github repository clear the cache and update the site essentially. 

Running ssh -vvv (please see edit) I've found that the server is looking in known_hosts to connect to github. Which is why it's using the old github user. How can I update this to be me?

Comment: The `known_hosts` file is used only to decide whether to complain about connecting to a *different* machine than last time, or to an unknown host: ssh stores a "host fingerprint" for each host, and if you ask to connect to the same machine again, it makes sure the fingerprint matches so that you are not offering credentials to a deceiver. (I moved your edit to your question, where it belongs...)

Answer (score 0):

The steps I followed to fix Forge to connect to GitHub over SSH are below:

1. [Github Generate SSH Key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)
2. [Add SSH Key to SSH-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent)
3. [Add new ssh key to git hub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)

   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my email"

   eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

   ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

   ssh -vT git@github.com

   [loads of technical guff excluded]
   Hi [my username]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not 
   provide shell access.

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub - copy and add that to the github account in by going Settings > SSH and GPG keys > Click New SSH key or Add SSH key.